# CSV file to ogive in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I'm a total newbie with R, and I'm trying to create an ogive graph (with values and cumulative frequency as the axises) from a csv file (just two row of values). Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Could you dput your data.

Comment: https://mega.nz/folder/5JgSFTYb#WLpnGjlBbfN4DDibaZ01Bg this is the data from the csv file, now I realize that there're more than 2 rows but I'm doing with dates per years. I send you my energy

Comment: Welcome to SO; Could you set out the code you have tried so far  and set out where the problem(s) is or are?

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to create a ogive graph for Elevation in your csv data, you can do this with `agricolae` package. If necessary `install.packages("agricolae")`

```r
library(readr)
library(agricolae)

# import csv file (should be in the same directory)
volcano_data_2010 <- read_csv("volcano_data_2010.csv")

# histogram of data, not showed -> plot = FALSE
Elevation <- graph.freq(volcano_data_2010$Elevation, plot=FALSE)

# ogive red points
points<-ogive.freq(Elevation,col="red",frame=FALSE,
                   xlab="Elevation", ylab="Accumulated relative frequency", main="ogive")

# version 2
plot(points,type="b",pch=16,las=1,bty="l")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank u man but i think this doesn't work with pandas. can you traslate to pandas? haha sorry

Comment: @ClementePeláez You wrote "in R" in your title, said "I am a total newbie with R", and added the R tag to your question. Why are you surprised TarJae provided a solution in R? How are they supposed to intuit that you wanted a solution in python?